# jQuery DataTable - few questions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few questions about jQuery DataTables:

1. How can i do that arrow next and arrow previus in pagination will be active all time?
2. I use Ajax, and i pass only 10 results, but all results is more for example 300, so how can i set this value to all results?
3. When I choose options rows per page from drop down menu I want call my javascript function, how can I do that?

My function:

```
    function prepareDataTable(){$("#displayData").dataTable(
    {aaData:listCustomer.rows,
    bSort:false,
aoColumns:
    [{mDataProp:"name"}]})};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your 2nd question, you can specify your own length list (dropdown) by setting the parameter - **aLengthMenu**, you can find the example from http://datatables.net/ref as below:

```
// Setting the default display length as well as length menu
// This is likely to be wanted if you remove the '10' option which
// is the iDisplayLength default.
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, -1], [25, 50, 100, "All"]]
  } );
} );
```

The last **-1** is meant for "All".

For your 3rd question, to inject your own callback upon page changing. I did not find an existing API/plugin. However, I have a suggestion: you can customize [the plugin API](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api) - **fnLengthChange** to inject your desired behavior into it.